# Radio Button Group With Big Circles Java

Tags: java, swing, radio-button

For an Application in Java Swing (developed in netbeans), we need to create big circle exatcly like radio buttons, which means we have a group of circles that whenever the user clicks on one, it changes to a filled circle. The user can choose only 1 circle.

The working mechansim is exactly similar to radiobutton group only we need to have bigger circles. Any idea how we can do this?

Answer (score 5):

1. Use JRadioButtons
2. But give them no text (if this is a requirement, .... it may not be your requirement, I don't know).
3. Instead give them two ImageIcons, 1 for unselected which is an empty circle, and use `setIcon(Icon icon)` to do this.
4. And the other for selected that is an image of a filled circle, and use `setSelectedIcon(Icon icon)` to do this.
5. You can create your own images easily by drawing on a BufferedImage.

---

For example, the code below creates:

[image]    .....   ...... [image: animated version]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CircleIconEg extends JPanel {
   public static final String[] PLAYER_NAMES = {"John", "Bill", "Frank", "Andy"};
   private static final int BI_WIDTH = 40;
   private ButtonGroup btnGrp = new ButtonGroup();
   private static Icon emptyIcon;
   private static Icon selectedIcon;

   // create our Circle ImageIcons
   static {
      // first the empty circle
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(BI_WIDTH, BI_WIDTH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
      g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4f));
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      int x = 4;
      int y = x;
      int width = BI_WIDTH - 2 * x;
      int height = width;
      g2.setColor(Color.black);
      g2.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
      g2.dispose();

      emptyIcon = new ImageIcon(img);

      // next the filled circle
      img = new BufferedImage(BI_WIDTH, BI_WIDTH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      g2 = img.createGraphics();
      g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4f));
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      g2.setColor(Color.red);
      g2.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
      g2.setColor(Color.black);
      g2.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
      g2.dispose();

      selectedIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
   }

   public CircleIconEg() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 4));
      for (String playerName : PLAYER_NAMES) {
         JRadioButton radioBtn = createRadioButton(playerName);
         btnGrp.add(radioBtn);;
         add(radioBtn);
      }
   }

   private JRadioButton createRadioButton(String playerName) {
      JRadioButton rBtn = new JRadioButton(playerName, emptyIcon);
      rBtn.setSelectedIcon(selectedIcon);
      return rBtn;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      CircleIconEg mainPanel = new CircleIconEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("CircleIconEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 But, if this is the same one of the questions asked a few weeks ago, they are required to implement it by hand using custom painting and have all run within a single panel, blah, blah, stupid assignment, blah...